# Postgresql query in codeigniter 3 returns null when using not in function

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter-3

This is my first time using postgresql and I'm getting clueless when I encounter this trouble. At first, when I use this code, everything went fine

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('pegawai');
$query = $this->db->get();
return = $query->result();
```

But, when I use not in, it returns array(0) { }
here's the code

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('pegawai');
$this->db->where('pegawai.id_pegawai not in (select id_pegawai from user)');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

It's supposed to display 2 records as I've made 2 dummies for this query. Anyone can help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('pegawai');
$this->db->join('user', 'user.id_pegawai = pegawai.id_pegawai', 'left');
$this->db->where('user.id_pegawai is null');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Found it already :D